# MySQL multiple if blocks with insert statements failing

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a procedure in MySQL that reads entries from a view, and inserts rows into another table depending on various conditions. In this context, I have up to 4 possible `size_id` variables, named `my_size_1, my_size_2, my_size_3` and `my_size_4`. If they do not have a value, they are `NULL`. Writing the following expression in my stored proc results in a SQL error:

```
-- Insert recommendation options --
INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_1);

IF my_size_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
    VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_2);
END;

IF my_size_3 IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
    VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_3);
END;

IF my_size_4 IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
    VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_4);
END;
```

...however, removing the `IF` statements fixes the error. That is, the following will run just fine:

```
-- Insert recommendation options --
INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_1);

INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_2);

INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_3);

INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_4);
```

Why is that? This isn't the end of the world - I can just add a `DELETE FROM size_recommendation_options WHERE size_id IS NULL` afterwards, but all of the unnecessary inserts slow down the stored proc considerably. Why is the first block invalid SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the SQL error, specifically?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
  
  IF my_size_3 IS NOT NULL THEN
   INSERT INTO `size_recommendati' at line 65`

Comment: Just as an aside, unless `size_recommendation_options` is a reserved word in your copy of mysql, delete all the backticks from your SQL - they are just code noise.

Comment: Based on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if-statement.html , you must close `IF` blocks with `END IF`.

Comment: @biziclop Care to make that an answer? This was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` blocks must be closed with `END IF`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if-statement.html

```
13.6.5.2. IF Syntax

IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

In your case:

```
IF my_size_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO `size_recommendation_options`
    VALUES (my_size_recommendation_id, my_size_2);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a Store procedure?, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_val
     (
        IN  a_id                    INT(11)       , 
        IN  a_first                     VARCHAR(15)       
     )
BEGIN 
if 
    INSERT INTO t1(actor_id, first_name )
    VALUES (a_id, a_first) ; 
END 

mysql> call insert_val(10,'a');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 0 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> call insert_val(null,'a');
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'actor_id' cannot be null
```

The input value cannot be null, so you don't need to worry about the null insert.